# Term/Category for “Random Click” Games?

Tags: terminology

I’m trying to find out if there is an industry-standard term for the genre of games where you randomly click around to figure out what to do yet. That is, what category are games like *Samorost*, *Hapland*, *Tetsuo*, and such?

Finding games like *Mystery PI* or *Mystery Case Files* is simple enough, just do a search for "HOG (Hidden Object Games)" or "Seek and Find Games", or to find games like DOOM you search for "(First Person) Shooter", but what about these other games? How do you find these without a standard term? Are they called "random-click","click-around","manual-less", "unscripted" or something else?

Comment: this question is for [meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @IvanSolntsev I don't really agree, unless it's a "how do we tag", and we don't tag genres so it's not useful there anyway.

Comment: Not a gaming-industry thing, but the act of randomly clicking interface elements to see what works and what doesn't is often called "minesweeping" in UI design parlance.

Comment: Don't know about the others, but Samorost certainly doesn't require you to click around randomly. It's a point and click adventure game

Comment: @IvanSolntsev, then why is there an existing `terminology` tag?

Comment: @YiJiang'sEvilClone, yes, most do, but not always. That’s the point to the question, figuring out if there is a proper name.

Comment: Are you looking for the term "pixel hunt"?

Comment: @Synetech looks like I was wrong, your question already have answer

Comment: @SevenSidedDie, I suppose so. You should have put it as an answer instead of a comment. ☹

Comment: @Ashley Nunn, um, why the edit? What was the point of changing it to quotes (other than to make them blend in and be harder to see, especially across line breaks)? If this isn’t a good usage of code-blocks, then what is here?

Comment: @Synetech That's ok! I wasn't sure, and Agent's answer is better than mine would have been.

Comment: The edit was probably because code formatting has a particular meaning and isn't for non-code, aesthetic purposes.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie, again, what purpose would it have here? This is a gaming site, not a programming site, so “code”-formatting is not specifically (if at all) for actual code; it’s an artifact of the underlying StackExchange code. In fact, I think I used it perfectly properly because search terms are blocks of computer text. Using quotes makes them blend in and look like episode titles or something as opposed to computer data.

Comment: `Don't know about the others, but Samorost certainly doesn't require you to click around randomly. It's a point and click adventure game.`   Aren’t Sierra’s *-Quest* games “point-and-click”? *Samorost* isn’t really the same because it has no interface or commands, manual, or anything, you are given next to nothing and left to figure out what to do.

Comment: Samorost is NOT a random click game

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term for this is "[pixel hunt](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PixelHunt)" although I'd stop short of calling it a genre.  It's more a (often considered negative) game design element.

Hidden object and adventure games often employ this element, as do "[escape](http://jayisgames.com/tag/escape)" games.

Comment: Sounds good to me. I’m not sure it is widely used yet, but I imagine as more games like these become popular (Machinarium was one of the first commercial ones to exclusively use it), I would assume more people would want to find them, so your answer may help consolidate searches for them. ☺

Comment: @Syntech It, and a more swearing variant, have decades of use behind them. It might not be a *genre*, but when "pixel hunt" is used to describe a game, it's clear what part of the play experience is most prominent.